# Syntax question

Tags: word-usage, syntax

> Good men, the last wave by, crying how bright
>   Their frail deeds might have danced in a green bay,
>   Rage, rage against the dying of the light.

From Dylan's Poem [Do not go gentle into that good night](https://www.poets.org/poetsorg/poem/do-not-go-gentle-good-night)

"*The last wave by*" is this an adverb in the passive form that if written in an active voice would be: *by the last wave* --- indicating a presence of time?

Comment: I've added  source for you. Please remember to fully cite your sources and in the case of a poem that is available online you should link to the text of the full poem. Poetry is often not a good source for how English syntax works. Poets break all the "rules"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are layers of meanings.

"The last wave" refers to the most recent(=last) generation(=wave) of good men to go by, or perhaps the final generation of good men. It has allusions to the last stage of life of the "good men" and to a farewell wave to their loved ones, metaphorically it suggests a sea wave that will soon crash against the rocks of the "green pay"

The syntax is a shortening of "The last wave to go by" but poetry often breaks some or all the rules of syntax to create images.